# What is the regular expression for the "root" of a website in django?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I'm using django and when users go to www.website.com/ I want to point them to the index view.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
(r'^$', 'ideas.idea.views.index'),
```

However, it's not working. I'm assuming my regular expression is wrong. Can anyone help me out? I've looked at python regular expressions but they didn't help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have should work (it does for me).  Make sure it's in the top `urls.py`, and it should also be at the top of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Just put an empty raw regular expression: r''

I tested here and it worked perfectly.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include('homepage.urls')),
)
```

Hope it help!

EDIT:

You can also put:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'\?', include('homepage.urls')),
)
```

The question mark makes the bar optional.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way you can just use a generic view and go straight to template for your index page?:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'', 'direct_to_template', {'template': 'index.html'}),
)
```